# Using mod_scorm_insert_scorm_tracks

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, moodle, moodle-api

I'm interfacing my App with Moodle and I'm successfully calling `mod_scorm_get_scorm_sco_tracks` and `mod_scorm_get_scorm_attempt_count` via Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) for a given user (`userid`).

Now I want my App to push some SCORM tracks back to Moodle.
So I'm trying to use `mod_scorm_insert_scorm_tracks` but with no success.
The problem is that this method does not take an `userid` parameter, so I don't understand how to use it (and if I try to add `userid` to input params I get an `invalid parameter exception`).

I had kind of success (no error message) by sending this:

> scoid=206&attempt=2&tracks[0][element]=cmi.completion_status&tracks[0][value]=completed&tracks[1][element]=cmi.interactions.0.id&tracks[1][value]=multiplechoice_page_1_1&tracks[2][element]=cmi.interactions.0.learner_response&tracks[2][value]=White&tracks[3][element]=cmi.interactions.0.result&tracks[3][value]=correct&tracks[4][element]=cmi.interactions.0.description&tracks[4][value]=Which%20color%20was%20Garibaldi's%20white%20horse%3F&tracks[5][element]=cmi.interactions.1.id&tracks[5][value]=hotobject_page_2_1&tracks[6][element]=cmi.interactions.1.learner_response&tracks[6][value]=butterfly&tracks[7][element]=cmi.interactions.1.result&tracks[7][value]=incorrect&tracks[8][element]=cmi.interactions.1.description&tracks[8][value]=Where%20is%20the%20fish%3F&tracks[9][element]=cmi.score.max&tracks[9][value]=2&tracks[10][element]=cmi.score.raw&tracks[10][value]=1&tracks[11][element]=cmi.score.scaled&tracks[11][value]=0.5&tracks[12][element]=cmi.session_time&tracks[12][value]=PT0H0M15S&tracks[13][element]=timemodified&tracks[13][value]=1480947821&tracks[14][element]=userid&tracks[14][value]=26&tracks[15][element]=scoid&tracks[15][value]=206&wstoken=69f2471506c4c49ff47cd0de0c4c9f01&wsfunction=mod_scorm_insert_scorm_tracks&moodlewsrestformat=json

However, since I cannot specify the user those data belongs to, my user's attempts does not update (as predictable).
This is the response from Moodle:

> {"trackids":[44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59],"warnings":[]}

I've tried inserting the `userid` info into traks (`tracks[14][element]=userid&tracks[14][value]=26`) but still no luck.

So, the questions are:

1. Which user are those tracks inserted to considering that I'm calling it from an external app, so there's no logged in user in Moodle?
2. How can I specify that those tracks are for a give `userid`?

Answer (score 0):

the user identity comes from the HTTP Context of a full login into Moodle: you can't provide SCORM tracking info on behalf of any user but the actual logged-in user.

More at:

- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/d33c67bc4744f901bf389607cfbbb683ef1c7d80/mod/scorm/classes/external.php#L451
- https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/0b8e0c374f89ca20e5b9e7c9370761810811edc6/lib/externallib.php#L481

HTH,
Matteo